# Inserting object instead of string in MySQL in React/Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having troubles inserting data to MySQL from Express API Server, I'm getting the data from my React Client. I have 4 fields and one of them is not inserting correctly, you can see it in the below screen (the last 3 rows).

[image: screenshot]

This is my client (React) code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {



constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {datos: {}};
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var self = this;
  // On submit of the form, send a POST request with the data to the server.
  fetch('/todo/meterla',{
    method: 'POST',
    data:{
      task: self.refs.task
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(body){
    console.log(body);
  });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="TASK" ref="task"/>
          <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is mi server code:

```
// Add a new todo
app.post('/todo/meterla', function (req, res) {

   var task = req.body;

   var query = mc.query("INSERT INTO tasks SET ? ", { task: task }, function (error, results, fields) {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the client code, change `data` to `body` in the `onSubmit` handler:

```
fetch('/todo/meterla',{
  method: 'POST',
  body:{
    task: self.refs.task
  }
})
```

In the server code, change this line `var task = req.body;` to `var task = req.body.task;`.

Comment: I've added your variable but now I can't insert any field into the DB.

Comment: what does `console.log(req.body)` give you?

Comment: I get an empty { }